# Auto-import React in Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have a React application I'd like to setup to include React for certain files, without having to explicitly import the library (e.g. Next.js does something similar)

How would I go about implementing this in Webpack?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's more like a problem of babel. Let's say you've written a babel plugin to include `React` automatically, here's how you can apply it to those certain files under webpack:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /certain files/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { plugins: ['your-babel-import-react-plugin'] },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```